# Body not expanding to contain dynamically added descendants in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having a weird issue with Chrome and am hoping for a sanity check. I have the following web page:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height:100%;
  outline: 5px solid orange;
}

#app-container, .uof-page, .timeline-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="btn">Click me to add tall element</button>
  <div id="app-container">
    <div class="uof-page">
      <div class="timeline-container">
        <div class="mdl-grid discussion-thread">
          <div class="discussion-messages">
            Some initial content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var x = document.querySelector('.discussion-messages');
  x.innerHTML += '<p style="height:2000px;outline:1px solid red;">Foo</p>';
});
</script>
</html>
```

When I run this off my local file system, Chrome won't expand the body to accommodate new descendants when the button is clicked.

I tried to set up a test case with jsfiddle and couldn't get the behaviour to replicate. https://jsfiddle.net/r0ya42g9/

Anyone have any thoughts as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are making every child item a flex item when you are only supposed to make the container a flex item. Once you set the container as flex all children are flex. the example code doesn't give me an expanding div on any browser. This CSS below seems to be working for me.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height:100%;
  outline: 5px solid orange;
}

#app-container {
   display: flex;        

   flex-flow: column;
   flex: 1;
   min-height: 100%;
outline: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn">Click me to add tall element</button>
<div id="app-container">
<div class="uof-page">
  <div class="timeline-container">
    <div class="mdl-grid discussion-thread">
      <div class="discussion-messages">
        Some initial content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
var x = document.querySelector('.discussion-messages');
x.innerHTML += '<p style="height:2000px;outline:1px solid red;">Foo</p>';
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: If I omit `display: flex` on the child, then the user agent style of `display: block` is applied. I checked on another machine - Chrome v. 51.0.2704.106 - and the injected element bleeds out past the body.

Comment: I'm sorry then there must be other classes in your environment that are affecting your layout that I am not privy to.  I copied your code exactly as I saw it and applied the css you see above and I have no overflow. My body element expands with the injected elements. I'm on the same version of chrome.  You have at least two more classes that I don't have like mdl-grid for instance.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time, but the mark-up included is all there is. Can I ask what OS you are using?

Comment: sorry I couldn't help. I'm on windows 7.  I've included the rest of the code just incase there are differences I missed.  I would try my code out in notepad and see if it works for you.